# how to use a variable that is created inside a method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public String letterInput() {
    System.out.print("Enter letter of first position : ");              
    String letterInput = input.next();      
    return letterInput;
}
```

i cannot access the variable letterInput outside this method i get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. any help is welcome

```
String a = letterInput();    
System.out.println(a);
int b = numberInput();
String c = newLetter();
int d = newNumber();


Piece piece = board.getPiece(letter.indexOf(a),b);
```

I can print out the value of the letterInput method but i can't use it in the code below.

Comment: Show us how you are calling this method

Comment: Any chance that `input.next()` is returning null?

Comment: you are already returing it so you can use this....

Comment: @Leon - Nope. `input(),next` will block this thread until it gets a value.

Comment: You cannot access it outside the method. If you can, then you're shadowing the variable and accessing a class member variable that has the same name, and is probably uninitialized.

Comment: We need to know how `input` is defined and initialized, and how `letterInput()` is being called.

Comment: You can't access it. You can only copy its value.

Comment: You can use it's value only in calling method

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: you should tell the line where `nullpointer exception` is occurred .how did you initialize`input`?

Comment: @FastSnail it occurs on the last line i posted. i used scanner

Comment: @EfeImoloame `String letterInput = input.next();`you didn't show `input` how did you initialize it?show it

Comment: @FastSnail Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: What is `letter`? What is `board`? Are they initialized? It is not easy to help you here if we have to ask about every little piece of code :(.

Comment: @EfeImoloame plz post your complete code if you don't know even which one is null

Answer (score -1):

When you return a variable you can store it as a variable like:

```
String input = letterInput();
```

Which would store the returned value of letterInput() in input.

This happens because the letterInput variable is local to the letterInput() method and is deleted after the method is called.

Comment: okay i did this         String a = letterInput(); 
    System.out.println(a);
    int b = numberInput();
    String c = newLetter();
    int d = newNumber();
    
    
    Piece piece = board.getPiece(letter.indexOf(a),b);                   i can print out the value of letterInput() but i can't use it in the code below